# 'Verb' vs 'verbal' as modifiers

Tags: difference, modifiers

When both are used as modifiers, is there any difference in meaning or usage? like 'verb phrase', 'verbal construction', etc.

Comment: I think it is a useful question, so I'll repost my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *should* be a difference, and in many technical grammar texts a formal distinction is drawn; but, alas, such distinctions are not consistent from author to author, and are even less consistently observed across the community.

This is probably inevitable in a discipline which is constantly evolving and which is constrained to talk about language with language itself. We are constrained to use generally understood terms from traditional grammar, like *verb* and *verbal*, in order to be understood at all; but we have to use these to discuss novel concepts which are often at odds with traditional understanding. Each author has to find her own path through this minefield.